# Facebook Open Graph issue with affiliate link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to let users to share products on my site, with Facebook, using Facebook OG. In addition, I need to implement an affiliate link by [VigLink Everywhere](http://www.viglink.com/products/anywhere).

So, the URL being share should be something like:

**http://redirect.viglink.com/?key=475a93b990315b7d41088aeaf46264c9&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dev.buyvolo.com%2FDetails%3FdealId%3D11578%26variantId%3D11967**

I put this URL structure in og:url, so the page meta tags are as follows:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="vololocal:clothing" />
<meta property="og:url"   content="http://redirect.viglink.com?key=475a93b990315b7d41088aeaf46264c9&amp;u=http%3a%2f%2fwww.dev.buyvolo.com%2fDetails%3fdealId%3d11578%26variantId%3d11967" /> 
<meta property="og:title"   content="Helix Dress - Black Sequin" /> 
<meta property="og:description"   content="Killer black sequin body-con dress featuring silver accents with a plunging sweetheart neckline and curved hem. Zip closure at back, boning. Fully lined." />
```

The problem is - I'm having the following error when debugged with [Facebook OG Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/):

```
Error Must Be Fixed:
There was an error in fetching the object at URL 'http://www.dev.buyvolo.com/Details?dealId=11578&variantId=11967', or one of the the URLs specified via a redirect or the 'og:url' property including one of http://redirect.viglink.com?key=475a93b990315b7d41088aeaf46264c9&u=http%3a%2f%2fwww.dev.buyvolo.com%2fDetails%3fdealId%3d11578%26variantId%3d11967.
```

How can I fix this? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you [debug your own URL directly](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dev.buyvolo.com%2FDetails%3FdealId%3D11578%26variantId%3D11967), you will get _“Object at URL 'http://redirect.viglink.com/?key=475a93b990315b7d41088aeaf46264c9&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dev.buyvolo.com%2FDetails%3FdealId%3D11578%26variantId%3D11967' of type 'vololocal:clothing' is invalid because the domain 'redirect.viglink.com' is not allowed for the specified application id […]”_

Comment: so, what does that mean? do i need to change the app settings in facebook?

Comment: That means first of all you can not do what you want this way.

Comment: what do you suggest? in what way i can do what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct what CBroe via comment said. It's not possible to give a redirect url as og:url.

og:url must be the object url where you define via meta tag your og properties.

In your case og:url should be: http://www.dev.buyvolo.com/Details?dealId=11578&variantId=11967

(I'm not quit sure if fb likes GET parameters - better would be something like http://www.dev.buyvolo.com/Details/11578/11967.)

However - when you give fb the correct og:url you and a user clicks in facebook this link, you could check the GET paramters. Facebook sends you following parameters:

```
?fb_action_ids=<actionId>
&fb_action_types=<app_namespace>:<action>
&fb_source=other_multiline
&action_object_map=<action_object_map>
&action_type_map=<action_type_map>
&action_ref_map=[]
```

So if you detect fb_action_types with your app and action, then you could redirect to your affiliate page which redirects the user back to your site.

I know this sounds ugly, but looks like this is the only way to get your affiliate work with your user's stories.